# How to set UTF-8 encoding in solr-php client to store hindi content in solr

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, solr, hindi

Can Any one help out to set UTF-8 encoding in solr-php client.The out put in solr After adding document is As below-

```
"info_type": "news",
    "title": "???????? ??????? ?? ?????? ????? ???? ?? 106 ???? ?? ???? ??? ????"
```

The above Question marks were hindi content stored in UTF-8 format.

Below is the Request Parameter for adding document in Solr by PHP Client

```
$options = array
(
'hostname' => 'HOST_NAME',
'login' => 'USER',
'password' => 'PASS',
'port' => 'PORT_NUMBER',
'path' => 'SOLR_NAME/CORE_NAME');
$client = new SolrClient($options);
$doc = new SolrInputDocument();
$updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);
$client->commit();
```

Comment: Solr uses UTF-8 by default - where are you outputting the content?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh Solr-PHP client doesn't support UTF-8 in default, That's why its Showing ????? mark in solr admin. I'm looking for option/Area where I can set character set encoding in **solr-php client**